# What is the correct syntax for Firebird's default constraint?

Tags: sql, default, firebird

```
create table students (
  tnum char(9) PRIMARY KEY CHECK (tnum SIMILAR TO 'T[:DIGIT:]{8}'),
  ssn varchar(9) UNIQUE NOT NULL CHECK (ssn SIMILAR TO '[:DIGIT:]{9}'),
  first_name varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  credits numeric(3, 0) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
```

Why is this not working? If I remove the "default 0", it works but if I leave the "default 0" in it doesn't work. So what is the correct syntax for the default constraint?

Answer (score 2):

Try to change the order of your syntax:

```
credits numeric(3, 0) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL
```

Then it should be as defined in the [`CREATE TABLE` syntax](http://www.firebirdtest.com/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-ddl-tbl.html#fblangref25-ddl-tbl-create):

```
CREATE [GLOBAL TEMPORARY] TABLE tablename
    ...
    (<col_def> [, {<col_def> | <tconstraint>} ...])
    ...;

<col_def> ::= <regular_col_def> | <computed_col_def>

<regular_col_def> ::=
  colname {<datatype> | domainname}
  [DEFAULT {literal | NULL | <context_var>}]
  [NOT NULL]
  [<col_constraint>]
  [COLLATE collation_name]

...
```